# Java, Spring Security : Disable 2 logins from single browser when authenticated from backend

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I am using Spring-security for authentication and authorization. In one of the features, we are sending invitation to users to join the application. When the user clicks on the email link, I login the user from backend.

If there is an user who is already logged in, the session from old user is not removed. I have set in the XMl to create a newSession, but that is not helping either. The result is I have 2 users logged in the same browser. ANy ideas, Thank you.

security-application-context.xml code :

```
 <security:http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
    <security:http create-session="ifRequired" use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <security:form-login login-page="/login" username-parameter="j_username" password-parameter="j_password"
                             login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" default-target-url="/canvaslisting"
                             always-use-default-target="false" authentication-failure-url="/login?error=auth"/>
        <security:remember-me key="_spring_security_remember_me" user-service-ref="userDetailsService"
                              token-validity-seconds="1209600" data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
        <security:logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="https"/>
        <security:port-mappings>
            <security:port-mapping http="80" https="443"/>
        </security:port-mappings>
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/" success-handler-ref="myLogoutHandler"/>
        <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession">
            <security:concurrency-control session-registry-ref="sessionReg" max-sessions="5" expired-url="/login"/>
        </security:session-management>
    </security:http>

    <beans:bean id="sessionReg" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl"/>
```

Controller code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/activatemembership/{token}")
    public String activateMembershipForExistingUser(){
boolean val = this.groupMembersService.activateMembers(token,true);

}
```

Service layer code :

```
// Logout is true when clicked from email. 

  @Override
    public boolean activateMembers(String token, boolean logout) {
        try {
            String[] parts = token.split(TOKEN_SEPARATOR);
            String username = parts[0].toLowerCase();
            Long groupAccountId = Long.valueOf(parts[2]);
            GroupAccount groupAccount = this.groupAccountService.getGroupObjectOnlyById(groupAccountId);
            Person person = this.personService.findPersonByUsername(username);
            if(logout) {
                Person loggedInUser = this.personService.getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser();
                if (!(loggedInUser == null)) {
                    loggedInUser.setOnlineStatus(null);
                    this.personService.directPersonUpdate(loggedInUser);
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);

                }
            }
//Other service layer code 
 if(logout) {
                    Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
                    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
                    Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(person, null, authorities);
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                }
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: What is the problem with the second session? If you really don't want more than one session, you should change your `max-sessions="5"` attribute.

Comment: @dur : If I change that to 1, users cannot login from 2 devices. This problem is regarding 2 users in the same browser.

Comment: The backend doesn't know that the browser is the same.

Comment: Maybe you can generate a browser specific key (something like a MAC- or IP-address) and add it with JavaScript to every request? So you can check the browser at the backend.

Comment: @dur : It does work on my localhost though.... How does it know on my localhost then? And I am trying to logout the currentlyauthenticated user...that request is then tied to the browser...

Comment: There should be no difference between localhost and other hosts. The server doesn't know, that you are using the same browser. But if you use the same browser and the same brower session (for example just open a tab) the browser will send the session cookie. In this case you are using one session not two, because the server gets the session cookie. That means, you are already logged in and you don't get a login page.